# Text Trimming without ellipses in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to customize `TextBlock` control to remove its ellipses(three dots at end) for `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"`. But since TextBlock does not have template property I cannot customize its trimming ellipses. Is there a way to remove those dots in case ellipses shown?

Comment: Maybe you can use an `IValueConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no official way to do this. what you could do is abuse **TextWrapping** property instead.

Remove the trimming and set TextWrappping to WrapWholeWords this will move all remaining text to a next line. if you combine this with a **MaxHeight** that you hard code to the height of 1 line it should get the same effect.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" MaxHeight="30">
```

Comment: Not an elegant way to do this. But still very effective :) thanks